# How can I use an array as a feature element?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've made a feature consisting of a boolean arrays, so the weights are adjusted for the string they represent. But the arrays aren't being accepted as they are.

These are the two features I'm using. Targets are "genres" and training feature is "install_per_review"

```
9516    23.8
7236    20.4
5781     4.0
2409    12.5
6052    59.4
        ... 
9648     inf
6125   196.5
3305    11.7
8841     7.1
720     29.0
Name: install_per_review, Length: 500, dtype: float64
9516    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
7236    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
5781    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
2409    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
6052    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
                              ...                        
9648    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
6125    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
3305    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
8841    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
720     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
Name: genres, Length: 500, dtype: object
```

This converts an array of strings into an array of boolean arrays

```
genre_features = apps_dataframe["genres"]

# Multi-hot encoding
genres = set()
for genre in genre_features:
    genres.add(genre)

encoded_features = []
for genre in genre_features:
    genre_feature = []
    for g in genres:
        if g == genre:
            genre_feature.append(1)
        else:
            genre_feature.append(0)
    encoded_features.append(genre_feature)

apps_dataframe["genres"] = encoded_features
```

The data is then used in the model training

```
    my_feature = input_feature
    my_feature_data = apps_dataframe[[my_feature]]
    my_label = "genres"
    targets = apps_dataframe[my_label]
    .....
    sample = apps_dataframe.sample(n=500)
    feature_sample = sample[my_feature]
    label_sample = sample[my_label]
    print(feature_sample)
    print(label_sample)
    plt.scatter(feature_sample, label_sample)
```

But Tensorflow complains because I'm setting each element to an array (even though I want to)

````
  File "/Users/lukire01/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.3.6558/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py", line 45, in <module>
    main(ptvsdArgs)
  File "/Users/lukire01/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.3.6558/pythonFiles/lib/python/ptvsd/__main__.py", line 391, in main
    run()
  File "/Users/lukire01/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.3.6558/pythonFiles/lib/python/ptvsd/__main__.py", line 272, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/lukire01/Code/tf_demo/app_store_model.py", line 207, in <module>
    input_feature="install_per_review"
  File "/Users/lukire01/Code/tf_demo/app_store_model.py", line 97, in train_model
    plt.scatter(feature_sample, label_sample)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2862, in scatter
    is not None else {}), **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1810, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 4297, in scatter
    alpha=alpha
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 899, in __init__
    Collection.__init__(self, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 155, in __init__
    offsets = np.asanyarray(offsets, float)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 591, in asanyarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.```
````

Comment: Is this a one hot encoded array?

Comment: @JerryM. Yep, I put multi because I thought it would end up as a multi, but I went for a lazier option.